# Peano arithmetic at compile time

Tags: code-golf, compile-time

Peano numbers represent nonnegative integers as zero or successors of other Peano numbers. For example, 1 would be represented as `Succ(Zero)` and 3 would be `Succ(Succ(Succ(Zero)))`.

## Task

Implement the following operations on Peano numbers, at compile time:

- Addition
- Subtraction - You will never be required to subtract a greater number from a smaller one.
- Multiplication
- Division - You will never be required to divide two numbers if the result will not be an integer.

## Input/Output

The input and output formats do not have to be the same, but they should be one of these:

- A type constructor of kind `* -> *` to represent `S` and a type of kind `*` to represent `Z`, e.g. `S<S<Z>>` to represent 2 in Java or `int[][]` (`int` for 0, `[]` for `S`).
- A string with a `Z` at the middle and 0 or more `S(`s and `)`s around it, e.g. `"S(S(Z))"` to represent 2.
- Any other format resembling Peano numbers, where there is a value representing zero at the bottom, and another wrapper that can contain other values.

## Rules

- You may use type members, implicits, type constructors, whatever you want, as long as a result can be obtained at compile time.
- For the purposes of this challenge, any execution phase before runtime counts as compile time.
- Since answers must work at compile-time, answers must be in compiled languages. This includes languages like Python, provided you can show that the bytecode contains the result of your computation before you even run the code.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Example for just addition in Scala

```scala
sealed trait Num {
  //This is like having a method `abstract Num plus(Num n);`
  type Plus[N <: Num] <: Num
}
object Zero extends Num {
  //When we add any n to zero, it's just that n again
  type Plus[N <: Num] = N
}
final class Succ[N <: Num](n: N) extends Num {
  //In Java: `Num plus(Num x) { return new Succ(n.plus(x)) }
  type Plus[X <: Num] = Succ[N#Plus[X]]
}
```

Usage ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IKf2meL3TPu65sWUrq9r6g)):

```scala
//This is just for sugar
type +[A <: Num, B <: Num] = A#Plus[B]

type Zero = Zero.type
type Two = Succ[Succ[Zero]]
type Three = Succ[Two]
type Five = Succ[Succ[Three]]
val five: Five = null
val threePlusTwo: Three + Two = five
val notFivePlusTwo: Five + Two = five //should fail
val zeroPlusFive: Zero + Five = five
```

## Test cases

S is used for successors and Z is used for zero.

```
S(S(S(Z))) + Z = S(S(S(Z)))                 | 3 + 0 = 3
S(S(Z)) + S(S(S(Z))) = S(S(S(S(S(Z)))))     | 2 + 3 = 5
S(S(S(Z))) - S(S(S(Z))) = Z                 | 3 - 3 = 0
S(S(Z)) * S(S(S(Z))) = S(S(S(S(S(S(Z))))))  | 2 * 3 = 6
S(S(S(S(Z)))) / S(S(Z)) = S(S(Z))           | 4 / 2 = 2
Z / S(S(Z)) = Z                             | 0 / 2 = 0
```

### Some links to help you get started

- [Type-Level Programming in Scala](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) (a bunch of articles, including ones about Peano arithmetic) (for Scala)
- [Multiplication at compile time](https://michid.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/meta-programming-with-scala-part-ii-multiplication/) (for Scala)
- [Peano arithmetic in C++ type system](https://gist.github.com/vladris/2dc4f5a47d003da002a70f0c0184b0a3) (for C++)
- [Type arithmetic](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_arithmetic) (for Haskell)

Comment: This seems like a kind of non-observable requirement. What prevents us from converting the numbers to a regular representation, doing the arithmetic and converting back?

Comment: @xigoi I feel there is some validity in your comment, but wouldn't converting to regular numbers and doing the arithmetic happen in run time instead of compile time?

Comment: @Kaddath That depends entirely on the language.

Comment: Also, what determines whether the numbers are represented in Peano arithmetic? I flagged the question as "needs more clarity".

Comment: @xigoi You can convert to numbers and do arithmetic and convert back to Peano, as long as it happens at compile time. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @xigoi I've added rules for input and output now. Let me know if it needs more work.

Comment: You know, it's t isn't a good idea to edit the question after it's posted; but even in that case you can claim that the output is in assembly embedded at a specific location in the binary for the C++ compilation case.

Comment: @user202729 It isn't, but as xigoi pointed out, the question was unclear the way it was, so I had to edit it. I'm not sure what you mean about the C++ one, though. Do you that it could be interpreted as a Peano number somehow?

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166594/interpreted-arithmetic)

Comment: @WheatWizard Nice challenge, I probably should've restricted mine to one language and operation too.

Answer (score 8):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) assembly, 37 bytes

This is simply using macro expansion.

```
Z EQU 0
MACRO S(n)
(%n%+1)
ENDM
 DCW [expression]
```

#### Example

With the expression `S(S(Z)) * S(S(S(Z)))`, this gets compiled as:

```
00000000 Z                          
0x0                             Z EQU 0
                                MACRO S(n)
                                (%n%+1)
                                ENDM
                                ;DCW S(S(Z)) * S(S(S(Z)))
                                ;DCW (S(Z)+1) * S(S(S(Z)))
                                ;DCW ((Z+1)+1) * S(S(S(Z)))
                                ;DCW ((Z+1)+1) * (S(S(Z))+1)
                                ;DCW ((Z+1)+1) * ((S(Z)+1)+1)
0000   0006                      DCW ((Z+1)+1) * (((Z+1)+1)+1)
 ERROR SUMMARY - ERRORS DETECTED 0
               -  WARNINGS       0
```

(compiled with **as1600** from the SDK included with [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/%7Eim14u2c/intv/))

Comment: I've restricted the output to look like a Peano number now, but this answer is good since it was posted before I edited the question.

Answer (score 6):

## [C++](https://www.iso.org/standard/79358.html), 328 bytes

```cpp
#define T template<class
#define O T N>struct
#define W T A,class B>struct
#define U using t=
U int;O S;W a;W a<S<A>,B>:a<A,S<B>>{};O a<t,N>{U N;};W s{U A;};W s<S<A>,S<B>>:s<A,B>{};W m{U int;};O m<N,S<t>>{U N;};W m<A,S<B>>:a<typename m<A,B>::t,A>{};T A,class B,class V=t>struct d:d<typename s<A,B>::t,B,S<V>>{};W d<t,A,B>{U B;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZNb9pAEL3zK6aqGkEwISSHSmBW2u3dkUpIjpYxC7HiD@pdJ00Rf710dm1jGzaGQ5GQ0c68N2@@FvubzWDt@/v91yVfBTGHR5A82oSe5LYfekJ0SsMDmhwiZJr58nD4jIfU0o7Ajo1zyEQQr0FOO3MIYjl5gNnkGTz1tWc2JRYjY8@m1sxmhGx3aPdsaTlkOwdnskM3gb9o/isHaM@xQAxTgGeItjm1Ake2gw6SVPioJMcw8mPDYy/i@hADj6VFFUctgeL5NJVFKrAcLyugOAAZsj6RXAE6WFrOHBgG3R/Kd8A5BAo6mbgolq95Oukc/AxWG58EtmjwZOCDn8RC8t@bFLJYBOuYL@HNCzMOU7idwK7G1RoTS@iQy2hHGfTrSAfT1jYdzhivc8KK4BqH@4a8Rsoa30FIpX@VJlEJQu3FSGFcpJtVAuputgMDTEG1Cs2kWSIjsX1LjrnVVDWTrYnr5K51Cleq/MxyCiVIluP@8DQpQhQnSZznoyykPJTviT5EY3X2kvIi9Xfl2RkO4ccL91/RwiHOogWWSaZeLFZJGsF7kr7iDgexH2ZLDrpeLpoDKcqOuTjzPJVdIZfjcSBcgfrdN63EOsoQy0R6k3Ycij2Bjc7DMJsT2N0FMFWOE@C9AVifxLzMMMX9afdTlVduo3Y31QrldnfGTYnVjve9vHOPXEjwwhCSDU89maQCsG268XkrhWH8qFUtLDPs3SJJQrzFhez2YNsB/OSjQ/WIHpWK4gxVLszkwgqXZma0z1QmzQTL8cdb3ZWWolOjr5pxSsD6tI2AKQLaJAhWtTS7FMgUWJmjQeGgRaEwKtwZwjAVhn4ehg1oWxhTHjtTPa9b1EaX1POathGcryeDL2ohTqr8DVi@Kp9XetiifXlxpalRAEMB9IwANqRtAsw90I@UyyyN8cZUf0Q7vZQ/s1ivj15FD/AuXXNIVoeNrG7TTAZhID9I@5Le3NwAE22L6mKk4mYr5Av@K@OxXxFiAQUSkbIGhe6uguN7iQqA6351BejU05mcaFI6qPjvuqjWZcFl@mFhykAFsimmsGjm0OyyhjV1Rd4rd1uC3t3iW1qh7SLfXkddzerVJfKCWN2gu/1ffxV6a7EfIM3U7/dH3/8B)

`0` (`Z`) is represented by the type `int`. `Succ(N)` is represented by the type `S<N>`.

`A+B` is `a<A, B>::t`, `A-B` is `s<A, B>::t`, `A*B` is `m<A, B>::t` and `A/B` is `d<A, B>::t`.

---

## [C++](https://www.iso.org/standard/79358.html), 285 bytes

```cpp
#define U template<
#define Q U class N>struct
#define X(n,o)U class A,class B>struct n:T<i<A>::v o i<B>::v>{};
Q S;Q i{static const int v=0;};Q i<S<N>>{static const int v=1+i<N>::v;};U int i>struct T{using t=S<typename T<i-1>::t>;};U>struct T<0>{using t=int;};X(a,+)X(s,-)X(m,*)X(d,/)
```

This "cheatier" version (if this is allowed) is shorter. It simply converts type to int -> do operation -> convert back to type.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZNb9pAEL37V0wVNcLBhJAcKoGxtO49UppEys0yZiGr2GvqXZO2yH@9dHb9gR02hkNzwNHOmzdv3ngWos1mtI6i/f5iSVeMU3gGSZNNHErqWvXZA55GcSgE3HtCZnkkm9DLgDupXYeJUz79CgZ8@uQyl3jT6RZSYK6v/vN2xcx6gMfZA7CdkKFkEUQpFxIYl7Cd38wKFXIf3XvPMwEmQ4YhZELgsz5jdcGnXS4YX4OcP7ry94byMKGAGkYTxEtPJTRQ98Zr0EiCsZdB6Aztl4FwRviZOFf4uXTG9r7xpOG896DikWmA2XRNs5nV4AxRF58e7KDdEP21ySDngq05XcI2jHMKc7iZQdHi6q1ZunQW7SSHYTtTW6hiupyxnnXEqtw@cARb5DVStvgaIQf9qyxN6iTUXk0B6yJda3BtmHsPI2xBjRHDXtciIzHO9yO3GnO32ZY4q4S2KQKp@jPLqZQgWZn3h2ZpVaI6SXnZj4p49aF8T/UhBg9nrxmtWn9XSGs8hu@vNHrDCAWeJwu0SWYhF6s0S@A9zd6EdcF4FOdLCtqvAMNMinpiAa4hzeRAyOV0ykQgUH@w1UqcDx2iTZ49689DsUdpk9Np2M1R2u0ZacqOo8Q7Q2L7TSxthjnuTz9OOa9gk36YGoWC3Z6AKbEaeGeXk3uieFOFcQzphmahTDMBODY9@HKUwvD6EeewsL5h7xZpGuPVLOTAhp0F@Fe@OkS/oh@sIvgOHSC@CeJXkG5nZOirTroN1q9/6GIxR9Hpu9Q2EfhD0kfgKwLSJWCrVpsDAt4c/LpHg8JRj0JhVFgYyviqDPm8jD8ifWVMfRQmP6961Cbn@HlF@ghO@@nDF7UQRy5/Bb9clc@dHvdoX57tNDEK8FEAOSHAH5M@AeYZ6EdGZZ5xvDHVF1Ghl/JHzvX66FUMAe/SNYV01Wzk4TbNJYuZ/O31L@n19TX4om9RA6xU3WyVfEF/5pRHB0I0UCCRV3tQ6R6odJeoqIfrfnkJCLJ1J0ealA4i/rsuonU5cJ5@WJg6UIVcgi0suj10p6zTurqS8I0GPUVv8YdbUWk7C2tb6mpWP12SkHF1gxb7v9EqDtdiP0KaeTQcTr79Aw)

---

## C++ or C, 29 bytes

```cpp
#define Z 0
#define S(N)(N+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdCxDoIwEAbgnae44EKpjQXUxfQVWNy6mKaAIVFCbDfjq1tPUggg2C5Ne/flv@q2ZVetndsUZVU3JUjgQX8@RzmJcpoQZ6yytb4oY8qHjfDhuyUhBCh2CDG62cJshRkWcRCQheQULEiyY0bm4PU3Xg1TrMtQOqxIvp/NMLmUiXUS/5MpXs3Up8JYmCnupONqJl8Nu0H2mJz8VrjHihSldEGS0@7fiSbTcS910wV1Y@Gu6iYi8Hy5t65u6mocM7YQmtIk@QA)

This is even more cheaty, and relies on C having integer constant expressions and C++ having constant evaluation that can be run at compile time

Comment: I've restricted the output to look like a Peano number now, but this answer is good since it was posted before I edited the question.

Comment: I don't know how your second version works exactly, but it should be fine as long as input and output look like Peano numbers and aren't normal `int`s. Although if you make that your main answer, please don't delete the first one, it's interesting.

Comment: [320 bytes](https://pastebin.com/fMPgktNe)

Comment: The last one also works in Objective-C.

Answer (score 5):

### TypeScript, <s>618</s> 585 bytes

```
type R<T,U,V>=T extends U?V:T
type I<T>=R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<T,20,21>,19,20>,18,19>,17,18>,16,17>,15,16>,14,15>,13,14>,12,13>,11,12>,10,11>,9,10>,8,9>,7,8>,6,7>,5,6>,4,5>,3,4>,2,3>,1,2>,0,1>
type D<T>=R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<R<T,0,[]>,1,0>,2,1>,3,2>,4,3>,5,4>,6,5>,7,6>,8,7>,9,8>,10,9>,11,10>,12,11>,13,12>,14,13>,15,14>,16,15>,17,16>,18,17>,19,18>,20,19>,21,20>
type A<T,U>=T extends 0?U:A<D<T>,I<U>>
type S<T,U>=U extends 0?T:S<D<T>,D<U>>
type F<T,U,V=0>=S<T,U>extends[]?V:F<S<T,U>,U,I<V>>
type B<T,U>=U extends 0?0:U extends 1?T:A<B<T,D<U>>,T>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASgPAFQDQFUkDUB8BeBUIAewEAdgCYDOUKA-OgFwICwAUKJFAJKI7x9z9BA4UNEjxyAEwAGJJICMmJPICcc6UvkAOZSs0B2ZVs0A2Zfs0BWZSc0AWZZc0BmZXc2TlzzfOWTNsvKKSGryGkg6ekiGxkhmFkjWtkgOTkiu7nLpmnJKgZis7NAAIjzYYhXildWISLIA2gC6OeGewa7+KdmJKUpmaYbJOglqsWEhPsrh8m3B8q4z9l5WbqaOBjaaOvIJqkZKMroHvjIFbODQAIK1KDh4hMTkVNI0KPTXpQhK3LdnRVAAZRuOBQ+CIpEoUBeCHoQM+SlKv0KFygADEbhhsBpsEDkLcHhCKE06PR0bjUEo0NwsH8UQAhYHYUEEp5QmjSejM8Gs+Q0GHXBnIRGYJRfZEcACyjPJ+O5lGJMKlMsptI4AAlGVzHpDefJ6FK8ZgWZCXhyNUK4EjzhwAAple5yqi8s21eFncXQABaEAATgB7KDYKEeqAIADuAaD3G43v9IpDCAAFj6INAo4gI6roKi-QBXH2BriIZOprNogCWADc00Wc-mzmQIABjAA2AEMU1Am36SBRgFAAF6+v30KCxv0AblYjdbHeg3d7-eAEdH4cn0+b7c7C77UGAJYgq4PU5YM63857u4AZlXDxXqyez3Ou5f+xRywRR9xUbfMCfWC2EBLgeNotrmFBrqO1xJimEBIKGmaFjeD4AUBUDIRAoHgZBUDXD+1bwWumBIbeE5QAA9OR+A+v6PqjgA5JY9FQOWVAkH6-b0fo9Gof2Q7+lhFD4Xe1zjvBwnEUGGH-iwgHAbBgnjlBcBiaGB6SXux68XuEaCTBqbKWuhHqSRKGyWh+6wRK5YkNhB6jriB7GbBGn8eu5lLhGCDlgAthAEH2VAgoRs5paFu+BAnnJ6F5j6ADy1Y+jh6J1j6hGIUGy7udFbkJb6yUqcO6V+q5w4yZRsC1NQ8FYKOMAQGA7ZNtAoI2aGUBhuW+5QOgrAVdwXyjnFJDQD5fqdvubYkKGfVUfCQ0jVAgEUFQk3TcwLAVdB8G3KuUAANTULNgJVbt7UALRHZtVHosg1U9Zgo5Xi2frjQAFHgVEoAAlAdPXHYKO2Pe1ABUV0VQaQN7QApODVHmlDUBtlAiYQC2kAFv8V7jVANrHXag0sRQNo+r5EAfd9x3FLm0DAAGxBNomJDlk2bYtktvldW2wDlpe8H7qxUA9i2IAdeNADWVDYwWNnEAA5r6zznQoAB0x1JtAbNy+NXWJj5VARj64sxQWiblnLqMFrZPkAEaK-BNu5v2A3EVNZBQPCUA2ymbbG+WV5cFAPm+7TqM+UjJCi42DW+irQA)

#### Key

| Value | Syntax |
| --- | --- |
| Zero | `0` |
| Successor of `n` | `I<n>` |
| `n + m` | `A<n, m>` |
| `n - m` | `S<n, m>` |
| `n * m` | `B<n, m>` |
| `floor(n / m)` | `F<n, m>` |

#### Test Cases

```
type Zero = 0
type Two = I<I<Zero>>
type Three = I<Two>
type Four = I<Three>
type Five = I<Four>
declare const zero: Zero;
declare const two: Two;
declare const three: Three;
declare const five: Five;
declare const six: I<Five>;

let threePlusTwo: A<Three, Two> = five;
let fivePlusTwo: A<Five, Two> = five; // error: '5' is not '7'
let zeroPlusFive: A<Zero, Five> = five;

let threePlusZero: A<Zero, Three> = three;
let twoPlusThree: A<Two, Three> = five;
let threeMinusThree: S<Three, Three> = zero;
let twoTimesThree: B<Two, Three> = six;
let fourOverTwo: F<Four, Two> = two;
let zeroOverTwo: F<Zero, Two> = zero;
```

#### Explanation

- `R<T, U, V>` is a replacement function: It takes `T` as its main input and replaces `U` with `V`.
- `I<T>` and `D<T>` are used to change numbers by 1. I know that I hardcoded it to stop at 21, but unfortunately I can't go further due to TypeScript's recursion limit. I originally tried a different method that was easier to understand and to extend, but it hit the recursion limit even faster. Underflow is represented with `[]` (empty tuple).
- `A<T, U>` returns `U` when `T` = 0, and `A<T - 1, U + 1>` otherwise.
- `S<T, U>` returns `T` when `U` = 0, and `S<T - 1, U - 1>` otherwise.
- `F<T, U, V>` technically returns `floor(T / U) + V`, but `V` defaults to 0. It uses `V` to keep track of the answer.
- `B<T, U>` returns immediately when `U` is 0 or 1, and otherwise returns `B<T, U - 1> + T`.

TL;DR: A lot of recursion.

Dividing by zero gives an error (TS2589), which I think is the correct behavior.

#### Bonus

Modulo and primality test:

```
type M<T,U>=S<T,U>extends[]?T:M<S<T,U>,U>
type H<T,U>=U extends 1?1:M<T,U>extends 0?0:H<T,D<U>>
type P<T>=T extends 1?0:H<T,D<T>>
```

`M<T, U>` returns `T` mod `U`.
`P<T>` returns 1 when `T` is prime and 0 otherwise.
Like with division, these both give an error when attempting to use 0 where it doesn't make sense.

---

#### Original

The original answer was very similar, but with a small difference in how `F` was defined:

```
type G<T,U>=S<U,T>extends []?1:0
type F<T,U,V=0>=G<U,T>extends 1?V:F<S<T,U>,U,I<V>>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 547 bytes

```rust
struct Z;struct S<Z>(Vec<Z>);trait A<B>{type R;}impl<B>A<B>for Z{type R=B;}impl<B,N:A<B>>A<B>for S<N>{type R=S<<N as A<B>>::R>;}trait M<B>{type R;}impl<N>M<N>for Z{type R=Z;}impl<N>M<Z>for S<N>{type R=S<N>;}impl<P,N:M<P>>M<S<P>>for S<N>{type R=<N as M<P>>::R;}trait T<B>{type R;}impl<B>T<B>for Z{type R=Z;}impl<B,N:T<B>>T<B>for S<N>where<N as T<B>>::R:A<B>{type R=<<N as T<B>>::R as A<B>>::R;}trait D<B>{type R;}impl<P>D<S<P>>for Z{type R=Z;}impl<P,N:M<P>>D<S<P>>for S<N>where<N as M<P>>::R:D<S<P>>{type R=S<<<S<N> as M<S<P>>>::R as D<S<P>>>::R>;}
```

[Try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%23!%5Bfeature(type_ascription)%5D%0A%23!%5Ballow(bare_trait_objects)%5D%0A%0Astruct%20Z%3Bstruct%20S%3CZ%3E(Vec%3CZ%3E)%3Btrait%20A%3CB%3E%7Btype%20R%3B%7Dimpl%3CB%3EA%3CB%3Efor%20Z%7Btype%20R%3DB%3B%7Dimpl%3CB%2CN%3AA%3CB%3E%3EA%3CB%3Efor%20S%3CN%3E%7Btype%20R%3DS%3C%3CN%20as%20A%3CB%3E%3E%3A%3AR%3E%3B%7Dtrait%20M%3CB%3E%7Btype%20R%3B%7Dimpl%3CN%3EM%3CN%3Efor%20Z%7Btype%20R%3DZ%3B%7Dimpl%3CN%3EM%3CZ%3Efor%20S%3CN%3E%7Btype%20R%3DS%3CN%3E%3B%7Dimpl%3CP%2CN%3AM%3CP%3E%3EM%3CS%3CP%3E%3Efor%20S%3CN%3E%7Btype%20R%3D%3CN%20as%20M%3CP%3E%3E%3A%3AR%3B%7Dtrait%20T%3CB%3E%7Btype%20R%3B%7Dimpl%3CB%3ET%3CB%3Efor%20Z%7Btype%20R%3DZ%3B%7Dimpl%3CB%2CN%3AT%3CB%3E%3ET%3CB%3Efor%20S%3CN%3Ewhere%3CN%20as%20T%3CB%3E%3E%3A%3AR%3AA%3CB%3E%7Btype%20R%3D%3C%3CN%20as%20T%3CB%3E%3E%3A%3AR%20as%20A%3CB%3E%3E%3A%3AR%3B%7Dtrait%20D%3CB%3E%7Btype%20R%3B%7Dimpl%3CP%3ED%3CS%3CP%3E%3Efor%20Z%7Btype%20R%3DZ%3B%7Dimpl%3CP%2CN%3AM%3CP%3E%3ED%3CS%3CP%3E%3Efor%20S%3CN%3Ewhere%3CN%20as%20M%3CP%3E%3E%3A%3AR%3AD%3CS%3CP%3E%3E%7Btype%20R%3DS%3C%3C%3CS%3CN%3E%20as%20M%3CS%3CP%3E%3E%3E%3A%3AR%20as%20D%3CS%3CP%3E%3E%3E%3A%3AR%3E%3B%7D%0A%0Atype%20_0%20%3D%20Z%3B%0Atype%20_1%20%3D%20S%3C_0%3E%3B%0Atype%20_2%20%3D%20S%3C_1%3E%3B%0Atype%20_3%20%3D%20S%3C_2%3E%3B%0Atype%20_4%20%3D%20S%3C_3%3E%3B%0Atype%20_5%20%3D%20S%3C_4%3E%3B%0Atype%20_6%20%3D%20S%3C_5%3E%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20source%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.rs%2Fstatic_assertions%2F1.1.0%2Fstatic_assertions%2Fmacro.assert_type_eq_all.html%0Amacro_rules!%20assert_type_eq_all%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%24x%3Aty%2C%20%24(%24xs%3Aty)%2C%2B%20%24(%2C)*)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20_%3A%20fn()%20%3D%20%7C%7C%20%7B%20%24(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20trait%20TypeEq%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%20This%3A%20%3FSized%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20impl%3CT%3A%20%3FSized%3E%20TypeEq%20for%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%20This%20%3D%20Self%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%20assert_type_eq_all%3CT%2C%20U%3E()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20where%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20T%3A%20%3FSized%20%2B%20TypeEq%3CThis%20%3D%20U%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20U%3A%20%3FSized%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all%3A%3A%3C%24x%2C%20%24xs%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2B%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(_0%2C%20_0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(_4%2C%20_4)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(%3C_3%20as%20A%3C_0%3E%3E%3A%3AR%2C%20_3)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(%3C_2%20as%20A%3C_3%3E%3E%3A%3AR%2C%20_5)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(%3C_3%20as%20M%3C_3%3E%3E%3A%3AR%2C%20_0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(%3C_2%20as%20T%3C_3%3E%3E%3A%3AR%2C%20_6)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(%3C_4%20as%20D%3C_2%3E%3E%3A%3AR%2C%20_2)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_type_eq_all!(%3C_0%20as%20D%3C_2%3E%3E%3A%3AR%2C%20_0)%3B%0A%7D)

This is basically equivalent to the Scala version. It defines two structs, `Z` and `S<Z>`, and four traits that implement the operations (called `A`, `M`, `T` and `D` in the golfed code).

Readable version:

```rust
struct Z;
struct S<Z>(Vec<Z>);

trait Add<B>{type R;}
impl<B> Add<B>for Z{type R=B;}
impl<B,N: Add<B>> Add<B>for S<N>{type R=S<<N as Add<B>>::R>;}

trait Sub<B>{type R;}
impl<N>Sub<N>for Z{type R=Z;}
impl<N> Sub<Z>for S<N>{type R=S<N>;}
impl<P,N: Sub<P>> Sub<S<P>>for S<N>{type R=<N as Sub<P>>::R;}

trait Times<B>{type R;}
impl<B> Times<B>for Z{type R=Z;}
impl<B,N: Times<B>> Times<B>for S<N> where <N as Times<B>>::R: Add<B>{type R=<<N as Times<B>>::R as Add<B>>::R;}

trait Divide<B>{type R;}
impl<P>Divide<S<P>>for Z{type R=Z;}
impl<P,N:Sub<P>>Divide<S<P>>for S<N>where<N as Sub<P>>::R:Divide<S<P>>{type R=S<<<S<N> as Sub<S<P>>>::R as Divide<S<P>>>::R>;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 307 bytes

```cpp
#define _ struct
#define n typename
#define t template<n T
#define U{using X
_ Z;
t>_ S U=T;};

t,n B>_ s U=S<n s<n T::X,B>::X>;};
t>_ s<Z,T>U=T;};

t,n B>_ b U=n b<n T::X,n B::X>::X;};
t>_ b<T,Z>U=T;};

t,n B>_ m U=n s<T,n m<T,n B::X>::X>::X;};
t>_ m<T,Z>U=Z;};

t,n B>_ d U=S<n d<n b<T,B>::X,B>::X>;};
t>_ d<Z,T>U=Z;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFRa4MwFIXf8ysu9GVjDroOCtM0sP6F2lF8EY1ZCZhUmjgYZb/d5aYmtS0UMcg5@U5OrrzrXvecD8OsEd9SCyjB2GPPLQmCBvvbCV0pESULVqiuraygGvIob0@9kXoPO1JCkRHLStjAdpVnfxkhNtGwdopxysZhBtE03SVr5laGexAwtEhydgvVDtJQB8SJyLg3YDXNk@IOUx4zztOg/Bq4KatGtrhim7FnQ7VP9zVvyjZjWU8OJA4lDAxyRs7ThK@qPRE32spKDvygjQWpLRyF6VsLK3iDF9wzQc8txw0ZwSND/jSVFuxh8NyjBHPdb4INxadgjIH8VO8ZuSA/JSoOwVT8nB4fA4y3ktHfYcoyi26N7hLdZXDnF1fdsx8Xt4lsdBfu4JnUvO0bAVQe3LVFpRjBuqqSGp6e/eWbNOWH3gKlofzianbDPw)

- There's already a good C++ answer but I was missing template meta programming.
- Left newlines on the code for some "readability" , already subtracted 14 bytes.
- Basically S (succ) stores it's template type which is then recursively inspected inside the various operations (s=sum,b=subtract,m=multiply,d=division) to dig the Peano structure.